# how to create live obect using jquery

Tags: jquery

There is Json array and i am using it to display my error messages.

```
var errorMessages {
"E1":"Error Occured During Request Processing...",  
"E2":"&nbsp;Enter User Name"
}
```

Next i want to display error messages base on error id

```
function showMessage(errorId){
    $('#serverMsg').html('');
    var msg = $('#messageContainer');        
    if (errorId.length != 0) {
            $('#messageContainer').show();
            $('#serverMsg').html(errorMessages.errorId);
    }   
    $("#messageContainer").focus(); 
}
```

it gives me undfine.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean:

```
var errorMessages = {
  "E1": "Error Occured During Request Processing...",  
  "E2": "&nbsp;Enter User Name"
};
```

Also as Daniel said below make sure you realize that `errorMessages` doesn't have a property called `errorId`, if you want to use `errorId` to 'look up' the right message then you have to write it like:

```
errorMessages[errorId]
```

Comment: I think its a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#serverMsg').html(errorMessages.errorId);
```

try this

```
$('#serverMsg').html(errorMessages[errorId]);
```